# Is there a good way to calculate sum of range elements in ruby

Tags: ruby, range

What is the good way to calculate sum of range?

Input

```
4..10
```

Output

```
4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 49
```

Comment: @lurker 49 of course=)) typo

Comment: Why the mad rush to select an answer? Quick selections can discourage other answers and short-circuit those still preparing answers. There's no rush. Many here wait at least a couple of hours.

Comment: @CarySwoveland when two huge dogs want to be walked there is no time to correct mistakes!

Comment: we can now use `sum` in Ruby 2.4.0, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable` methods on Range objects, in this case use `Enumerable#inject`:

```
(4..10).inject(:+)
 #=> 49
```

Now, in Ruby 2.4.0 you can use [Enumerable#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum)

```
(4..10).sum
#=> 49
```

Comment: Since this is the selected answer, you may add 0 as the identity value, otherwise you'll get nil for empty ranges.

Answer (score 6):

I assume the ranges whose sums to to be computed are ranges of integers.

```
def range_sum(rng)
  rng.size * (2 * rng.first + rng.size - 1) / 2
end

range_sum(4..10)   #=> 49
range_sum(4...10)  #=> 39
range_sum(-10..10) #=>  0
```

By defining

```
last = rng.first + rng.size - 1
```

the expression

```
rng.size * (2 * rng.first + rng.size - 1) / 2
```

reduces to

```
rng.size * (rng.first + last) / 2
```

which is simply the formula for the sum of values of an arithmetic progression. Note `(4..10).size #=> 7` and `(4...10).size #=> 6`.

Comment: I would go with declaring a method with left/right boundaries without messing with ranges at all.

Comment: Cleverest answer, save compute cycle.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Enumerable#reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce):

```
range.reduce(0, :+)
```

Note that you need `0` as the identity value in case the range to fold is empty, otherwise you'll get `nil` as result.

Answer (score 2):

YES! :)

```
(1..5).to_a.inject(:+)
```

And for **visual** representation

```
(1..5).to_a.join("+")+"="+(1..5).inject(:+).to_s
```

Comment: Both `to_a` are unnecessary.

Comment: Oh good to know thank you i am new in ruby just, i had same issue before and as junior ruby developer i done that as in documentation :)

Answer (score 2):

```
(4..10).to_a * " + " + " = 15" 
#=> 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 15
```

:)