# Ruby #inject behavior is different from documentation

Tags: ruby, inject, enumerable

Taking a look at [Ruby documentation on `Enumerable` class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html) I noticed something interesting and I'd like to know why it happens this way.

At [**`#inject`** description](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) I've found these examples:

```
# Sum some numbers
(5..10).reduce(:+)                             #=> 45
# Same using a block and inject
(5..10).inject { |sum, n| sum + n }            #=> 45
# Multiply some numbers
(5..10).reduce(1, :*)                          #=> 151200
# Same using a block
(5..10).inject(1) { |product, n| product * n } #=> 151200
```

Notice that when `#inject` is used for multiplication, it receives an initial value of 1. I thought this was necessary because otherwise product would receive 0 as start value (as it happens in the sum) and the multiplication would also be 0. In fact, if I run

```
p (1..5).inject(0) { |prod, n| prod * n }
```

I got

```
0
```

But then I run

```
p (1..5).inject { |sum, n| sum + n } 
p (1..5).inject { |prod, n| prod * n }
```

and got

```
15
120
```

My questions are:

a) **Why the documentation includes this 1 as initial value when, in fact, it is not needed?**

and

b) **What is the behavior of `#inject` when it comes to initializing the object being injected?**

Comment: What do you mean by initializing the object being injected ?

Comment: I mean, how does Ruby proceeds the initialization. You explained it in a certain sense in your answer below.

Comment: Using the multiplicative identity (`1`) as the initial value in the  `(5..10).reduce(1, :*)` example was a poor choice as `(5..10).reduce(:*)` produces the same result. Similarly, `(5..10).reduce(0, :+)` would be a poor and misleading example.

Comment: Yes, as I edited in my answer, it initialises the object as the first element of the array.

Comment: I think the point of including `1` in the example is to demonstrate how to (if required) pass an initial value/total etc.

Comment: Agreed, @muistooshort. I see many poor examples in Ruby documents.

Comment: Agreed, @sagarpandya82. The problem here was the poor choice of values. One is hardly a good value, since one can't see its effect in the multiplication. The example would be better without using the multiplicative identity, as it was pointed in other comment.

Comment: @tokland makes a good point for why you might pass a multiplicative or additive identity [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40708047/5101493)

Comment: Well noticed @sagarpandya82.

Comment: Be careful with `reduce(1, :*)`. `[].reduce(1, :*) #=> 1` may not be what you want. Similar for `[].reduce(0, :+) #=> 0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your first question:

a) **Why the documentation includes this 1 as initial value when, in fact, it is not needed?**

inject does not take 1 as initial value, from the [apidock](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject):

> If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo, then uses the first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo.

Answer of second question lies in the answer of first itself, as it initialises the object as the first element of array on which inject is being applied.

Comment: It's also worth noting that it's often a good idea to seed in a default value to handle the case of an empty list: `[].inject(:+)` returns `nil`, but `[].inject(0, :+)` returns `0`.